# Disable Alt+Tab physical keyboard shortcut

Tags: xiaomi, external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mi-a2

Is there any way to disable the Alt+Tab shortcut when using physical keyboard on android phone ,I'm using xiaomi 
Mi a2 phone.